# Will SQQQ go back to 2018 level if QQQ will?

Tags: shorting-securities, leverage

It's a theoretical question, but i am not able to figure it out. Is the relation between SQQQ and QQQ close enough to expect SQQQ go back to where it was at certain point in time, if QQQ goes back to that point in time? I realize that there is internal friction and other stuff, but i can't see how far in time the coupling goes.

Comment: No.  If a $100 asset goes down 40% and up 66%, it's back to $100 where it started.  If the inverse, initially priced at $100, goes up 40% and down 66%, it's now $48, nowhere near where it started.  And SQQQ is not even a simple inverse, it is triple-leveraged inverse.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sounds like an answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt ok, that i understand. however, would it be just a simple inverse etf, would it actually do the same percentage as the underlying etf? like would it do 40% then 66%? i assumed, it's only right for small movements.

Comment: @TQQQ It's the same problem regardless of the scale. downward movements require a larger upward movement to get back to the same level, so if you reverse that, the larger downward movement is not overcome by the smaller upward movement

Comment: And yes, inverse ETFs are designed to have the same relative movement, just in the opposite direction. If they are _leveraged_ then they are supposed to move at a constant _multiple_ of the underlying stock/index.

Comment: Awesome, thank you guys

Comment: @glibdud: It's not, because it doesn't use actual data for QQQ and SQQQ since 2018, it uses a very simplified illustration with only one large movement (and a large movement is not representative of performance of a daily-rebalanced leveraged fund).

Comment: Imagine that QQQ goes up 100%, then SQQQ goes down 100%, right?

Comment: That's why i think it only works for small increments. What if it's 200%?

Comment: @user253751: It depends whether it does so in one day or as a number of much smaller steps.

Comment: @BenVoigt how is it arranged? do they hold a short position? I would guess that TQQQ holds 3 shares of QQQ, while SQQQ holds a -3 short. But in that case, they wouldn't have to rebalance every day.

Comment: @TQQQ: Don't guess, visit https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/xnas/sqqq/portfolio and scroll down to "Holdings"  As you can see, SQQQ actually is invested in a bunch of derivative contracts with banks as the counterparties.

Comment: Oh, great. Was hard to find it on google not knowing what i am looking for. So it contains NASDAQ100 swaps of all kinds?